# Changing Timestamp format for Date-Time in Excel/Pandas/Python?

Tags: python, time-series, excel

I have a excel data with time stamp format like this "2019-06-10T14:05:00+05:30"
[YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS], I want it to be converted into "2019-06-10 14:05" [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM],

Is it possible to convert into required format using Excel or Python Libraries?
or any other way?

Thank you!

Comment: one way is storing the data as dataset and changing the format of column date-time with string rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using python's *pandas* library
- *strftime()* helps obtain specific format
- *to_datetime()* of pandas helps convert string to datetime object

```
import pandas as pd
dt = "2019-06-10T14:05:00+05:30"
dt = pd.to_datetime(dt, errors='ignore')
transformed_date = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
print(transformed_date)
print(type(transformed_date))
dateType = pd.to_datetime(transformed_date)
print(type(dateType))
```